# A word for "positive side effect"

Tags: single-word-requests

> Planting a tree will help the environment. And, as a [positive] side
>   effect, you will have a nice decoration in your backyard.

Is there a word I can use to describe a side effect that is also positive?

I considered ***bonus***, like:

> Planting a tree will help the environment. And, as a bonus, you will have a nice decoration in your backyard.

Is there something else I can use?

Comment: When you already have a perfectly good word that works for your purpose, but you want more, you can use a thesaurus to come up with a huge number of possibilities. In print (_Roget's Thesaurus_ being the most famous book of its kind), or online at http://thesaurus.com, you can find just about all the alternatives and synonyms you would ever want.

Comment: What about benefit?

Comment: You could simply just say, "Planting a tree will help the environment. *Plus*, you will have a nice decoration in your backyard."

Comment: your original choice of *bonus* is likely the most popular term.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has mentioned [***spinoff***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spin-off) *- a by-product or incidental result of a larger project.* Not that it would really apply in OP's example, but I agree with @Jim that such a trivial context hardly seems to justify talking up the "fringe benefit". It's not like the person planting a tree in his backyard for environmental reasons would need *reminding* that it could also be seen as an ornamental "enhancement" - after all, that's the *normal* reason people plant trees in their backyards.

Comment: I'm with JosephNeathawk, "bonus" serves the purpose better than any of the suggested answers. @Omega You mention "bonus" but don't say why you're looking for something else. Is there something about "bonus" which makes you think there might be a better word?

Comment: How about as a perk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the words : Benefit, advantage, feature, plus point and more..

Comment: I think these words by themselves aren't perfect substitutes in OP's usage.  It needs to be an ***added*** **benefit**, ***added*** **advantage**

Comment: @Jim I've also heard "side benefit."

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you get rid of the "positive side effect" verbiage and replace it with one word:  moreover.

> Planting a tree will help the environment; moreover, you will have a nice decoration in your backyard.

Or, with a few more words:

> By planting a tree you will not only help the environment, but you will also have a nice decoration in your backyard.

Or, simpler yet:

> Planting a tree helps the environment and adds value to your backyard.

I like this one.  It has good balance.  You've got one action with two results.  Planting does two things: it helps and it adds value.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest "to boot"? I.e.:

> Planting a tree will help the environment. And you will have a nice
>   decoration in your backyard to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I like the phrase: positive externality.

> "A positive externality (also called "external benefit" or "external economy") is an action of a product on consumers that imposes a positive effect on a third party."

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Externality#Positive)

Comment: *Positive externality* is borrowed from economics jargon. Could you provide an explanation as to what it means, why you propose it, and perhaps examples of its use elsewhere?

Comment: As a positive externality, you’ll have some nice decoration in your back yard? That sounds utterly bizarre to me.

Comment: Might be a little technical, but it's accurate. "A positive externality (also called "external benefit" or "external economy") is an action of a product on consumers that imposes a positive effect on a third party."

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Externality#Positive)

Answer (score 0):

How about [*synergistically*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synergistically):

> in a synergistic or interactive manner

derived from [*synergy*:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synergy)

> 1. The interaction of two or more agents or forces so that their combined effect is greater than the sum of their individual effects.
> 2. Cooperative interaction among groups, especially among the acquired subsidiaries or merged parts of a corporation, that creates an enhanced combined effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "furthermore" as an equally good substitute for "moreover" in the stated context.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a single word but I feel these get the point across much better than a single word can:

**icing on the cake**

[American heritage dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=icing+on+the+cake&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

> An additional benefit to something already good.

**cherry on top**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/the-cherry-on-the-cake-or-on-top)

> A desirable feature perceived as the finishing touch to something that is already very good: *the car is faster than a Ferrari, but the cherry on the cake is the price*

---

In your example:

> Planting a tree will help the environment. And, as **icing on the cake/the cherry on top**, you will have a nice decoration in your backyard.